# Change the size of a script output (google gadget) using javascript/css

Tags: javascript, css

I want to add [this google gadget](http://www.gmodules.com/ig/creator?synd=open&url=http://www.astroviewer.net/gadgets/iss/iss-position.xml&lang=fr) to my web site

As you can see, you must choose a specific constant size then you can generate the script to add to your html page. My problem is that I want to change the size of the output of this script according to the resolution of the user's screen for example (otherwise, it can be smaller or bigger...and ugly :p )

I tried several things but nothing worked.

If I choose for example: 320 and 200 as the width and height of the gadget, here's the code generated:

```
<script src="//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.astroviewer.net/gadgets/iss/iss-position.xml&amp;synd=open&amp;w=320&amp;h=200&amp;title=ISS+Position&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>
```

I tried to change the src of this script using javascript (to modify this part: ;w=320&h=200&). But once I change it, the script output doesn't appear anymore...-_-

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: In the `src` line, all the `&amp;` should be just `&`. That a typo?

Comment: Doesn't it need to be 'redrawn' after modifying sizes ?

Comment: The code is directly generated with &amp, I don't think this is the problem.

What do you mean by 'redrawn' ?

thanks